# Message Queue For Serial Port I/O

Tags: c#, serial-port, message-queue

I'm communicating with an external device from C# via a COM port in Windows. I'm thinking that the best way to move messages back and forth between my code and the device is via a message queue. This way, I can push the request onto the stack, and handle the response whenever it's received from the device. Hopefully this will free up the front end, especially since the `Serialport` response is async. Can anyone recommend a queue that I can use that's fully contained within my app with no need for an external DB or MSMQ? Thanks!

Comment: Does the queue have to live beyond your app's lifetime? That is, can you lose unsent messages if your app exits or crashes?

Comment: ConcurrentQueue? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I would recommend a state machine.  See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38536373/2009197).

Comment: @n8wrl yes, it only needs to live for the lifetime of the app.